# Is it possible for a Citation Jet not to have an APU or AIR COND?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, cessna-citation

In reviewing a number of CESCOM10 reports it has become apparent that some of the aircraft don't report APU hours (instead they report AIR COND).

Is it possible that a Citation Jet doesn't have an APU?

For those reports that do report APU hours, no AIR COND hours are reported ... is it possible that there are Citation Jets that have APUs and no AIR CONDs?

Comment: Are you asking for a particular Citation airframe, I Imagine the answer may vary across the model line as "Citation" encompasses a variety of airframes.

Comment: If it has pressurization, it has air conditioning.

Comment: @RalphJ But not necessarily a freon AC system that might require reporting.

Comment: I think that systems with APU typically don't have independent AC systems that need to be tracked for maintenance purposes which is why you never see any CESCOM10 reports that have both APU and AIRCOND hours.  Conversely, without an APU, there is typically some kind of AC system that is independent and therefore tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a Citation jet to not have an APU, two of them that come to mind are the CJ2 and CJ3 aircraft. An aircraft with an APU can have an independent air conditioning system or not, it just depends on the installation and manufacturer. Some airframe manufacturers use engine (or APU) bleed air to condition the cabin air temperature. Something like an APU would have overhaul limits similar to an engine, propeller, or a combustion heater like in smaller aircraft. Anything with a life limit would have to be tracked, so that could be individual components of a larger system, such as the starter/generator of an APU, or a compressor motor of an air conditioning system. I think what you're seeing is a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

A very large number of Cessna Citations do not APUs including (but not limited to):

CJ (Although actually a CitationJet)
CJ1
CJ1+
CJ2
CJ2+
CJ3
CJ3+
CJ4
CE500 Citation
CE501
CE550
CE551
CE560  (not including the CE-560XL)